# PHP unit-testing how to mock a method NOT to be callable

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, mockery

In a function that I want to test I have the following check

```
if (!is_callable(array($object, $methodName))) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
        sprintf(
            'Unable to call method %s::%s() on object $%s',
             get_class($object),
             $methodName,
             $objectName
        )
    );
}
```

How can I test the exception ?

How can I make a [MOCKERY](https://github.com/padraic/mockery) object containing a method that is not callable or is maybe a property ? I am not sure.

Comment: are you using some framework?

Comment: @Sakuya84 yeap, Mockery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply instanciate a empty `StdClass` object.

```
public function testCallable()
{
    $object = new \StdClass();

    $object2 = \Mockery::mock('\StdClass')
        ->shouldReceive('myMethod')
        ->andReturn('foo')
        ->getMock();

    $this->assertFalse(is_callable(array($object, 'myMethod')));

    $this->assertTrue(is_callable(array($object2, 'myMethod')));
}
```

Comment: This is kinda of what I did in the end. But the problem was that the stdClass is not available (using entities) so I had to create a test Entity for my needs. Your answer was close enough. I will accept it within the timeframe. Also check if you like the discuss here: https://github.com/padraic/mockery/issues/231#issuecomment-30135464